# Xcode warning: _startToken(startToken) will be initialized after _deleteConfigs(deleteConfigs)

Tags: antlr4

I just upgraded to the C++ 4.7.2 runtime source and when I build in Xcode, I get the warning

```
 _startToken(startToken) will be initialized after _deleteConfigs(deleteConfigs)
```

This is in the second constructor of NoViableAltException.

Obviously I can fix this locally (warnings are considered errors in my environment) but this should probably be propagated back into the source tree. I've no idea who does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually fork [ANTLR4 on Github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4), make your changes and create a pull request from that. You need to have a Github account for that.

However in such a simple case I can probably do the change(s), just give me a patch.

Comment: Yeah, I figured but not really being part of the ANTLR community (I'm just a humble enduser), it wasn't obvious that I should do that. I've emailed you the change.